# Dynamic vertical line in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, visifire

How can I build a dynamic vertical line in SiliverLight 5. We are using Visifire charts.

Scenario is like user can plan a future date and that will be mark as a yellow vertical line. And also there can be more than one vertical line.

It should look like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to use a ["TrendLine"](http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_gauges_documentation.php) to draw vertical lines at whatever position you choose.  For a vertical "trend line", just set the ["Value"](http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_gauges_documentation.php) and [Orientation](http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_gauges_documentation.php) properties.

[image: Vertical line example]